# Scalding operate on group after groupBy

Tags: mapreduce, scalding

I am writing a scalding job.

Here's what I want to do: first groupBy a Key. That should give me a bunch of (Key, Iterator[Value]) pairs for each Key (correct me if I'm wrong here). Then for each Ley, I want to apply a function on its associated Iterator[Value].

How should I do this? I am currently using a groupBy followed by a mapGroup. I get an Iterator[Value] but that iterator only has one value for some reason. mapGroup is not getting to operate on multiple values. It's important that I get to see all the values for any given key at the same time. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You are doing everything right. mapGroup gives you (K, Iterator[V]) pair which contains all values for your key. Could you show a code you use? Could you show your test data? I guess there is indeed 1 value for each key

Comment: @AlexandrPriymak you are correct, the test data indeed had only 1 value for most keys! Thank you